# BST remove implementation

Tags: javascript, tree, binary-search

As practise, I implemented a BST and also the `remove()` method, but I figured I always have to check if the node being deleted is coming from the left child or the right child of its parent, then reset the pointers. I basically check that in all cases in my remove. Is there any way I can avoid this and make the code more readable and easier understandable by others?

```
removeNode = function (node, key) {

     if (key > node.key) {

         removeNode(node.rightChild, key);

     } else if (key < node.key) {

         removeNode(node.leftChild, key);

     } else { // find the node

         if (node.leftChild.key === null && node.rightChild.key === null) {

             node.parent.leftChild.key = null;

             node.parent.rightChild.key = null;

             return true;

         } else if (node.leftChild.key !== null && node.rightChild.key === null) {

             // to see the current node is the left or right child of the parent, reset the pointer
             if (node.parent.leftChild === node) {

                 node.parent.leftChild  = node.leftChild;

             } else if (node.parent.rightChild === node) {

                 node.parent.rightChild  = node.leftChild;
             }
             node.leftChild.parent = node.parent;

         } else if (node.leftChild.key === null && node.rightChild.key !== null) {

             if (node.parent.leftChild === node) {

                 node.parent.leftChild  = node.rightChild;

             } else if (node.parent.rightChild === node) {

                 node.parent.rightChild  = node.rightChild;
             }
             node.rightChild.parent = node.parent;

         } else { 

             var leftMaxNode = predecessorNode(node);

             if (node.parent.leftChild === node) {

                 node.parent.leftChild  = leftMaxNode;

             } else if (node.parent.rightChild === node) {

                 node.parent.rightChild  = leftMaxNode;

             }

             leftMaxNode.rightChild = node.rightChild;
             node.rightChild.parent = leftMaxNode;



         }

         return true;
     }
 },
```